# Patricia Merkle trie and LevelDB in each block

Tags: nodes, hash, merkle-patricia-tries, leveldb, ethereum-design

I have a few questions regarding Ethereum's modified Patricia Merkle trie and LevelDB.

1. Does each block only contain the root hash of all the tries (World State, transaction, and receipt) or the entire tries themselves? If latter, where are they? The header or the body?
2. If the answer to 1 is "only the root hashes", then when a full client first downloads the blockchain and validates each block, how do they validate that the root hash of each trie is correct?
3. As far as I understand, the modified Patricia Merkle trie is designed so that a leaf node can efficiently be located since the Radix trie aspect of it allows you grouping of the same keys together.  What's the purpose searching the trie when you can search LevelDB directly?  Is it because adding/updating an account state requires first finding it in the trie? Or other reasons?
4. Does each block contain its own version of LevelDB or only the latest block?